# Cambiar fecha de número a letra - Excel - Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010

Tags: excel, vb, formulas, visual-basic

Lo que me gustaría es lograr que, por ejemplo, la fecha 4/11/2022 me aparezca como "cuatro de noviembre de dos mil veintidós".

Ya intenté con varias fórmulas, pero no he conseguido tal cual lo que quiero, que es muy específico.

Comment: Hola. Excel a través de sus funciones y herramientas no puede, o bueno, podrías intentar estructurar una gran fórmula y/o que extraiga los datos de una base. Lo más cercano a lo que quieres te lo pueden dar las macros.

Comment: ¡Gracias! justo tuve que hacer una gran fórmula, la comparto en respuestas

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. ¿Probaste con formato fecha larga? Es muy parecido a lo que pides y no hay que complicarse con fórmulas.

Comment: Sí, solo que me temo que en mi trabajo me pidieron que apareciera de manera muy específica, por lo que lo necesitaba así, que saliera completa.

Answer (score 4):

No pude encontrar una manera de solucionarlo directamente con funciones específicas, sin embargo terminé haciendo la siguiente **fórmula en mi celda destino** (considerando que D2 tiene escrito en texto 02/10/2022):

> =CONCATENAR(SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="01","uno de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="02","dos de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="03","tres de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="04","cuatro de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="05","cinco de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="06","seis de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="07","siete de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="08","ocho de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="09","nueve de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="10","diez de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="11","once de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="12","doce de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="13","trece de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="14","catorce de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="15","quince de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="16","dieciséis de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="17","diecisiete de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="18","dieciocho de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="19","diecinueve de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="20","veinte de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="21","veintiuno de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="22","veintidós de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="23","veintitrés de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="24","veinticuatro de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="25","veinticinco de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="26","veintiséis de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="27","veintisiete de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="28","veintiocho de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="29","veintinueve de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="30","treinta de ",SI(IZQUIERDA(D2,2)="31","treinta y uno"))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) & TEXTO(D2, "MMMM")) & SI(DERECHA(D2,2)="22"," de dos mil veintidós", SI(DERECHA(D2,2)="23","de dos mil veintitrés", SI(DERECHA(D2,2)="24"," de dos mil veinticuatro")))

**Dando como resultado:** dos de octubre de dos mil veintidós

Comment: En lugar de la retahíla de `SI`, mira la función `ELEGIR`; para el día será algo como `=ELEGIR(DIA(D2);"uno";"dos";"tres";"cuatro";"cinco" . . .)` (verás que también uso la función `DIA` para extraer el día de la fecha); para el año, si nos limitamos a 2022-24, sería algo como `... &"de dos mil "&ELEGIR(AÑO(D2)-2021;"veintidós";"veintitrés;"veinticuatro")`. Mi Excel está configurado para España, reemplaza `;` por `,` si es necesario.